# winforms namespace order - 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'AAA.System'

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a project named AAA.System that contains some simple base functions to be shared by all of our other projects.  This has been around for about 5 years or so, and we have many projects that reference it which are all working fine.

Now, I am creating a new project (WCF service) and I'm having some issues with namespace resolving.  Specifically, I have these usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
```

at some point, I have this line of code:

```
string fqdn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

which is generating the error:

`The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'AAA.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

So it seems that somehow the visual studio (2010) is trying to resolve to `AAA.System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` instead of `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()`, but I don't have any using statements indicating the use of `AAA.System`.  What am I missing here that is indicating to the compiler to use AAA.System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the namespace of the class you are calling the following line set to `AAA`?

```
string fqdn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

e.g.

```
namespace AAA
{
    static void M()
    {
        string fqdn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(); 
    }
}
```

To fix it you should be able to prefix the line with `global::`.

```
string fqdn = global::System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

Or just add `System.Net` to you using directives

Comment: No - all the namespaces on the new project are AAA.AuthService

Comment: Oh, okay.  So then when a namespace is being resolved, it walks up from the class's namespace first before it looks in global:: ?

I knew it looked in the current namespace, but didn't realize it walked up the tree.

Comment: Yeah. At work every namespace starts with the same prefix (e.g. `EEE`) and I always write `Controls.MyControl` instead of `EEE.Controls.MyControl` when I need to.